# ReactJS: Material UI floating button onTouchTap calls url the ListItem beneath it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My `Component` looks like

```
const style = {
    margin: 0,
    top: 'auto',
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 'auto',
    position: 'fixed',
};
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            open: false
        }
    }

    toggleDrawer = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    handleAddMenu = () => {
        console.log("Opening New Menu Form");
        this.props.history.push("/addMenu");
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <AppBar
                    title="SpicyVeggie"
                    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
                    onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer}
                />

                <Drawer
                    docked={false}
                    width={300}
                    onRequestChange={this.toggleDrawer}
                    open={this.state.open}
                >
                    <AppBar title="SpicyVeggie" onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer} />
                    <MenuItem
                        primaryText="Menu"
                        containerElement={<Link to="/menu"/>}
                        onTouchTap={() => {
                            this.toggleDrawer()
                        }}
                    />
                    <MenuItem
                        primaryText="Summary"
                        containerElement={<Link to="/summary"/>}
                        onTouchTap={() => {
                            this.toggleDrawer()
                        }}
                    />
                </Drawer>

                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <FloatingActionButton
                        style={style}
                        mini={true}
                        secondary={true}
                        onTouchTap={this.handleAddMenu}>
                        <ContentAdd />
                    </FloatingActionButton>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When I render the `app` it looks like
[image]

so when I click on `Add`, it triggers `onTouchTap` of the `ListItem` beneath the button.

The second time, when there is no `ListItem` under it, and I hit "Add", it calls the correct `onTouchTap` event for the Add.
[image]

How do I fix it for the first case, to give priority to `onTouchTap` for `FloatingActionButton`?

Comment: What version of React/Material-UI are you using?

Comment: `"material-ui": "^0.17.4"`. This is the version I have

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to intercept the event object of the action and stop the propagation of the click in the function that you call.

All you have to do is pass the event to the function and then call stopPropagation, like so:

```
handleAddMenu = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Opening New Menu Form");
    this.props.history.push("/addMenu");
}
```

Comment: This is not helping the situation, the behavior is still the  same.